# Problem writing shapefiles with writeOGR in R

Tags: r, gdal

I've been getting an error in a script that iterates over some text files in a directory, does some data manipulation and writes to a ESRI shapefile using writeOGR from the rgdal package in R. I keep getting an error after a certain number of files are written (appears to be about 43-44 individual files, or ~14 complete shapefiles, as each shapefile creates a number of files).

The error is usually something like

```
GDAL Error 4: Unable to open ./test_8.shp or ./test_8.SHP
```

Additionally, after the script has crashed I get an error like

```
 cannot open file 'file_test.R': Too many open files
```

When I try to read or do anything with another file.

```
showConnections
```

does not show *any* open files at this point.

Here is some code that reproduces the problem:

```
library(gstat)
library(rgdal)
data(meuse)

coordinates(meuse) = ~x + y

for (i in 1:50){
    writeOGR(meuse,'.',paste('test',i,sep="_"),driver="ESRI Shapefile")
}
```

I'm using R 2.12.2 on OSX. Error happens on both 64 bit and 32 bit versions.

Comment: Probably be better of opening and closing the connection for each loop. for(x in 1:50) { opencon ... closecon }

Comment: A shapefile has (at least) a .shp, .dbf, and .shx. Do I need to open and close all of these? Also, in rgdal versions prior to 1.8.0, I don't think I can overwrite existing files (and on a server to which I do not have admin privileges, I need to run this script on rgdal version 1.7.1), so I may not be able to write the shapefile if the file already exists.

Answer (score 4):

Your code worked for me on Ubuntu 11.04 and R 2.13, might be worth also to try `writeSpatialShape` from the `maptools` package.

Comment: I ended up with the same error (R version 2.13.0, Mac OSX). I guess there's a maximum number of connections that GDAL can open when writing to ESRI shapefiles.  Your solution to use `writeSpatialShape` overcame this limitation.

Comment: Code worked for me on Windows 7 too. Sounds like an OSX related bug.

Comment: I was having a similar issue with `writeOGR()`: I'd try to rewrite a file in the same session and it'd be blocked. `writeSpatialShape()` does the trick.